# creating a "statically" accessible struct inside struct

Tags: c++, struct, static

I am trying to create a statically accessible struct inside a struct.
So I can access it like:

```
Foo::bar::foobar
```

Code example:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct bar
    {
        static std::string foobar;
    };
}
```

However, C++ doesn't know something as a static struct, so is it possible?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong with your existing code? With only small modifications your code [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/cfMzjE1sz). I made `foobar` `inline` but you could also provide an out-of-line definition [like so](https://godbolt.org/z/xW81MMKbh). It's not clear to me what exactly you want.

Comment: The declaring was where it went wrong. Appreciated